# Issue creating and editing a nested resource rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to make sub categories of categories in nested resources. The issue that I have is that it doesn't seem to work. All i get are `undefined method`sub_category_path' for #<#:0x007f8fcde33550>
Did you mean?  new_category_path`swell as`first value of a form cannot be nil`.

My controller methods are as follows:

SubCategory Update:

```
@category = @subcategory.category.id
if @subcategory.update(subcategory_params)
  flash[:success] = "Subcat name updated"
  redirect_to category_sub_category_path(@subcategory)
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

SubCategory new:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id]) # TODO:subcategory.category.id? 
@category_sub = @category.sub_categories.new
#@subcategory = @category.sub_categories.new
```

SubCategory create:

```
@subcategory = SubCategory.new(subcategory_params)
if @subcategory.save
  flash[:success] = "subcategory created"
  redirect_to category_sub_category_path
else
  flash[:error] = "subcategory failed"
  render 'new'
end
```

And my private methods:

```
  private

   def set_sub_category
      @subcategory = SubCategory.find(params[:id])
   end

   def subcategory_params
      params.require(:sub_category).require(:name, :category_id)
   end
  end
```

I don't have a SubCategories index, the viewing of the SubCategory is based off clicking a link in `Categories index.html.erb` which can be seen here:

```
<%@categories.each do |c|%>
<ul class="listing">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <li class="article-title">
                <strong><%= link_to "#{c.name}", category_path(c)%></strong>
                <% c.sub_categories.each do |s|%>
                  <div>
                    <%=link_to s.name, category_sub_category_path(c,s)%>
                  </div>
                <%end%>
            </li>
            <li><small>
                <!--Pluralise here-->
            </small></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</ul>
<%end%>
```

And then in my `SubCategory show.html.erb`:

```
<span class ="badge"><%= link_to "Edit sub category name",
                       edit_category_sub_category_path([@category, @subcategory])%></span>
```

And in my `SubCategory edit.html.erb`:

```
  <%=form_for([@category, @subcategory], :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"})do |f|%>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
               <%= f.label :subcategory%>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Update Sub Category", autofocus: true%>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <%=f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"%>
            </div>
        </div>
    <%end%>
```

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

Errors 
am now getting this error

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"81lwz0NufTqdOni+4wPRO4Vnmeis9f32+sqSN‌​sxTXZY7ufyR8hTvF86KQ‌​wdMjcOP2DQJibK66croW‌​48Uhos9+A==", "sub_category"=>{"name"=>"Gold", "category_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update Sub category", "category_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}`

because wrong number of arguments (given 2 expects 1)

```
def 
  subcategory_params params.require(:sub_category).require(:name, :category_id)
end
```

FIXED: Just took out the second .require, no idea why I put that there

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace of error?

Comment: It seems that one of the `@category, @subcategory` is nil. So can you post the edit action of sub category of the controller.

Comment: @BalaKarthik the edit action is just subcategory = SubCategory.find(params[:id]) since I have a before_action :set_sub_category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned in the comments the edit action must be like

```
def edit
  @subcategory = SubCategory.find(params[:id])
end
```

So the value `@category` is nil this has caused a error `first value of a form cannot be nil`.

Make the edit action as

```
def edit
  @subcategory = SubCategory.find(params[:id])
  @category = @subcategory.category
end
```

Assuming that you have relation between category and sub category.